# Adding data from firebase causes an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

Pleas help, I have a problem when I want to add user point data from a Firebase database

[image]

I want to add the previous user's point to the newly obtained point. This is the code that I use

```
final DatabaseReference userDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userRefEmail);
    userDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userCurrentPoint = dataSnapshot.child("point").getValue().toString();

            if (userCurrentPoint != null) {
                int finalPoint = Integer.parseInt(userCurrentPoint) + poin;
                userDataRef.child("point").setValue(String.valueOf(finalPoint));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

But when I use it, there is an infinite continuous addition of points to the firebase database, how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SingleValueEvent` instead of `ValueEventListener`, with `SingleValueEvent` it will only be called once:

```
    userDataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userCurrentPoint = dataSnapshot.child("point").getValue().toString();

            if (userCurrentPoint != null) {
                int finalPoint = Integer.parseInt(userCurrentPoint) + poin;
                userDataRef.child("point").setValue(String.valueOf(finalPoint));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```